# Ajax problem when browsing with domain name

Tags: django, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, http-status-code-403

I have a Django website hosted under AWS/Cloudfront.

Every form contains a CSRF token and is caught with jquery and then processed with AJAX.

When accessing the website with the Elastic Beanstalk URL everything works fine.

**Url pattern working**: http://example.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com

When accessing the website with the domain name, all the Ajax calls are refused with a 403 error.
**Url pattern not working**: https://www.example.com/

I have the strong intuition there is a parameter to change in AWS, but for me, it is a black-box.

Thank you in advance for reading and maybe answering this.

**EDIT 1**: I think the only problem is the posted parameters not being parsed to the controller (views.py)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should verify SSL/TLS requirements,
or some docs like :
[Amazon Using HTTPS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https.html)

When I launched a AWS serveur, I had to configure for http and https.

Answer (score 0):

As expected I finally found a single parameter to change:

CloudFront > Select your Bucket > Distribution parameters > behaviors > Edit > Select managed-AllViewer for the Origin policy.